# Cakephp how to load I18nModel fixture for testing?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, testcase

I want to test my app using cake tests features and I have problem with I18nModel used in my AppTranslateBehavior (its custom behavior). I got an error:

**Table i18n for model I18nModel was not found in datasource test.**

In the test case i added 'plugin.languages.i18n' (fixture is inside a plugin) to $fixtures and my fixture looks like:

```
class I18nFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

public $name = 'I18n';
public $table = 'i18n';
public $import = array(
    'table' => 'i18n',
);}
```

I also tried

```
class I18nModelFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

public $import = 'I18nModel';
public $table = 'i18n';
public $fields = array(
    'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
    'locale' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 6, 'null' => false),
    'model' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false),
    'foreign_key' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false),
    'field' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false),
    'content' => array('type' => 'text')
);
public $records = array();}
```

and many other variations but none of them worked.

I'm I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever found solution to this problem? would be great if you can publish it back on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the core translates fixture that cakephp provides:

```
class MyModelTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array(...,'core.translates');
    ...
}
```

Edit : fixtures name is core.translate**s**, not core.translate